# DocumentSymbolProvider does not fire when switching to already opened file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We are writing a VSCode extension using the API to find methods in an opened file.
Everything works so far, when we open a new file in the Extension Development Host the methods get found, so the DocumentSymbolProvider fires / executes.

The procedure of the extension would be like this:

- Open File A --> new DocumentSymbolProvider which runs the code to collect all methods from a list of wanted methods
- All found methods from File A get displayed in our extension's side panel
- Open File B --> new DocumentSymbolProvider runs again, now for this file, and collects all methods
- All found methods from File A get replaced by found methods from File B
- [This step doesn't work] Going back to File A --> DocumentSymbolProvider should run its code / collect all methods from this file again, and display them in side panel
- But what our code currently does: No data from File A gets collected, the extension still displays all data from the last 'new' file, in this case File B

But It doesn't fire when we switch back to an already opened file. In order to fire again you have to close the file (tab in vscode) and open it again.

Is there something to implement so that the DocumentSymbolProvider fires also when switching file tabs? We alrerady tried putting

```
onDidChangeEmitter = new vscode.EventEmitter<vscode.Uri>();
onDidChange = this.onDidChangeEmitter.event;
```

into the DocumentSymbolProvider so it looks like this:

```
class JavaDocumentSymbolProvider implements vscode.DocumentSymbolProvider {

    onDidChangeEmitter = new vscode.EventEmitter<vscode.Uri>();
    onDidChange = this.onDidChangeEmitter.event;

    public provideDocumentSymbols(document: vscode.TextDocument, token: vscode.CancellationToken): Thenable<vscode.SymbolInformation[]> {

       // code to find methods
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should it fire when you just switch to the tab? The file wasn't even changed, so it's just a waste of resources to regenerate symbols.

Comment: @LexLi our extension scans the current editor/code for methods from a list, but when open a new file, search for methods (everything works) and go back to the other file, it still provided the data from the last 'new' file. So we want it to run the DocumentSymbolProvider also when switching to an already opened file.


The found methods get displayed in a sidepanel our extension creates, so we need the methods from the open editor and therefore it's on purpose to scan and provide again when switching tabs

Comment: Please edit your question to give a detailed example (using file A and B if you want to describe multiple files). Long comments without details or diagrams don't help much.

Comment: @LexLi I just put a detailed description of what we want our extension to do and what it currently does in my question

Comment: That's a lot easier to understand now and I can see what's wrong. Will post an answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct logic should be,

1. Hook to file open/change event to generate new symbols (and only keep them in memory).
2. Hook to active text editor change event to display the symbols from the newly activated document.

For step 2, you should refer to `vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor`,

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window

Comment: thank you, this would mean we have to assign the uri of the file where the functions came from, save this for later and call them when the uri of the open editor matches with the uri of one set of saved symbols/functions? I also wonder if there's a way to manually trigger the `onDidChangeTextDocument` event. Because when I only put one space into a line of the open file, the provider is able to fire again, meaning that a 'simulated change on the file' when changing tabs would help us too.

Comment: okay, nvm, I just figured out how to work with this correctly and now we can use `onDidChangeActiveTextEditor` correctly, it works. Thank you!